# display loading message with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am trying to display loading message before sending ajax request, and on `success` callback, hide the message again.

```
$('#uploadForm').submit( function () {
    var fileExists;
    if((typeof reference !== 'undefined') && reference) {
        $('#loading').css('display', 'block');
        CheckFileExists(reference).success(function(response) {
            if(response.status === 'true') 
                fileExists = true;
            else if(response.status === 'false')
                fileExists = false;
            $('#loading').css('display', 'none');
        });
        if(fileExists) {
            alert('Sorry, file already exists!');
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});

function CheckFileExists(el) 
{
    var fi = el; // GET THE FILE INPUT.
    if(fi.value !== "") {
        var file_name = fi.files[0].name; // FILE NAME
        return $.ajax ({
            url: "task/file-check",
            data: { file_name : file_name},
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false                
        });
    }       
}
```

But this will make the ajax request first, alert pops up, and finally the `message` appears.

I also tried keeping the if-else inside `setTimeout`:

```
$('#uploadForm').submit( function () {
    var fileExists;
    // load
    appendData();

    setTimeout(function() {
        if((typeof reference !== 'undefined') && reference) {           
            CheckFileExists(reference).success(function(response) {
                if(response.status === 'true') 
                    fileExists = true;
                else if(response.status === 'false')
                    fileExists = false;             
                $('#overlay-procurement').remove();
            });
            if(fileExists) {
                alert('Sorry, file already exists!');
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }, 3000);
});
```

This will also submit the page (page reloads) while the ajax request is also being made (loader appears and alert pops up).

Also tried `beforeSend` but found out it doesn't work with `async: false`.

Comment: you're right - `async: false` it won't works. As the code is waiting for ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

Do it after submit

```
$('#uploadForm').submit( function () {
   $('#loading').css('display', 'block');
```

and on success

```
   $('#loading').css('display', 'none');
```